# Consulta SQL server en php devuelve valores nulos

Tags: php, sql-server

No se si tengo algun problema en la sintaxis de la consulta pero en mi PHP recibo un parametro por POST y ese parametro lo uso para que la consulta me devuelva todas las filas que contengan ese nombre

```
  $concepto=$_POST['concepto'];
  $sql= "select con.ID_CONCEPTO, con.DESCRIPCION
  from CONCEPTOS_SAT as con
  where con.DESCRIPCION like '%'$concepto'%'";

  $params = array();
  $consulta = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $query); //ejecuta la query
  $filasEncontradas=sqlsrv_num_rows($consulta);
  echo $filasEncontradas;
```

Quise saber si encontraba alguna fila pero no me tira nada en el "echo" 
¿mi error  puede estar en la sentencia like?

Comment: Un `print_r()` de $consulta te muestra algo?

Comment: Tengo una consulta donde también utilizo `LIKE` y agregué las comillas como tú las estás usando `'%'$concepto'%'` y me marca error, colócalas de esta manera `LIKE '%$concepto%'` y comenta que sucede.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa dos cosas:

1. La sintaxis del operador LIKE en este caso debe ser: `like '%$concepto%'";`
2. A la función sqlsrv_query le mandas $query, debes mandarle la variable $sql

Quedando así:

```
 $concepto=$_POST['concepto'];
 $sql= "select con.ID_CONCEPTO, con.DESCRIPCION
 from CONCEPTOS_SAT as con
 where con.DESCRIPCION like '%$concepto%'";

 $params = array();//No lo ocupas pero por algo lo tienes acá definido
 $consulta = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sql); //ejecuta la query
 $filasEncontradas=sqlsrv_num_rows($consulta);
 echo $filasEncontradas;
```

> El valor que viene del post debe ser sanitizado para evitar inyección SQL.